# Does graph theory predate computer science?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, math-history

I am curious if mathematicians came up with the idea of Graph Theory (*the study of pairwise relationships between objects visualized as nodes connected by edges*) before the field of Computer Science necessitated it? Or was Graph Theory a natural consequence of Computer Science born out of the need to visualize/evaluate large and complex pairwise relationships?

Comment: The Wikipedia page on graph theory has a history section that shows examples of work far pre-dating computer science. Had you looked there before posting your question?

Comment: Graph theory is my favorite example of a subject that transitioned from pure mathematics to applied mathematics. At first it was contrived to solve a puzzle that didn't have any broad applications and is now a cornerstone of computer science.

Answer (score 19):

The Königsberg bridge problem was solved by Euler in 1736, whereas Charles Babbage was born in 1791.

Comment: Okay this really puts things into perspective...